# Когда выполняется main?

Tags: java, ооп

Есть Class1, в котором создаётся экземпляр Class2:

```
public class Class1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class2 class2 = new Class2("Hello");
    }
}
```

Class2:

```
public class Class2 {

    static String hello;

    Class2( String hello){
       this.hello = hello;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print(hello);
    }
}
```

Почему при таком создании экземпляра Class2 не исполняется его метод main? Разве создание класса не должно автоматически исполнять его метод main?

Comment: при созданни класса выполняется только конструкто....а метод - это метод...его надо вызывать

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Т.е. в Class2 метод main, по сути, не имеет смысла? Его логичнее назвать просто public void myPrint() и вызвать в конструкторе или в class1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your code
}
```

Является, в некотором смысле, маяком для компилятора. Он позволяет определить, что класс, в котором расположен этот метод, является стартовым и с него нужно начинать работу приложения.

Создание экземпляра класса вызывает автоматический вызов конструктора этого класса:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Что подразумевает выполнения метода-конструктора в классе Foo, а не выполнения его main.

```
class Foo {
    public Foo() {
        // Конструктор
    }
}
```

Таким образом, в случае, если вы хотите, чтобы ваш класс **Class2** при создании выводил на экран переменную hello, то вам необходимо определить метод для этого:

```
    public class Class2 {

    static String hello;

    Class2(String hello){
       this.hello = hello;
       printHello();
    }

    void printHello(){
       System.out.println(this.hello);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

метод main используется как точка входа приложения. 
Если вы хотите передать аргумент при создании объекта:

```
Class2 obj = new Class2("Hello");
```

то вам нужно добавить конструктор и в нем уже работать с аргументами.
Или создать метод в классе **Class2** и вызывать его уже после создания объекта, передавая в него аргумент.

```
obj.myPrint("Hello");
```